# How to install php7.0-mbstring in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, mbstring

Hi i want to know how to install mbstring in ubuntu i m not expert in linux, so i search but i can't find the answer, the cmd line

```
1 - php -m
```

don't show the package. also 
the cmds line

```
2- sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstrin
3- sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

don't show anything please any one can help

Comment: What do you mean "don't show anything" ?. Answer 3 seems correct.

Comment: It seems that you have a typo in `php7.0-mbstrin`. It must be `php7.0-mbstring`. Also, I've just tried to execute `apt search mbstring` and it says that `php7.0-mbstring` exists in 16.04.

Comment: Can you include the output of each single command?

Comment: Thank's all iĺl post all the output in each single command

Comment: Try running `apt update` before install

Comment: no it doesn't work,  the cmd update work but not work when im searching for mbstring

Comment: @StanislavYakubenko cmd apt search mbstring show 
`En train de trier... Fait`
`Recherche en texte intégral... Fait`

Answer (score 0):

1 - php -m

`[PHP Modules]
calendar`
`Core`
`ctype`
`date`
`exif`
`fileinfo`
`filter`
`ftp`
`gettext`
`hash`
`iconv`
`json`
`libxml`
`mysqli`
`mysqlnd`
`openssl`
`pcntl`
`pcre`
`PDO`
`pdo_mysql`
`pdo_pgsql`
`pgsql`
`Phar`
`posix`
`readline`
`Reflection`
`session`
`shmop`
`sockets`
`SPL`
`standard`
`sysvmsg`
`sysvsem`
`sysvshm`
`tokenizer`
`xmlrpc`
`Zend OPcache`
`zlib`

`[Zend Modules]`
`Zend OPcache`

2- sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstrin

`Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances

Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet php7.0-mbstrin
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-mbstrin'
E: Impossible de trouver de paquet correspondant à l'expression rationnelle « php7.0-mbstrin »`

3- sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

`Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances

Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet php-mbstrin`

4- apt-cache search php7.0

`libapache2-mod-php7.0 - langage de script inclus dans du HTML et exécuté côté serveur - module Apache 2
php7.0 - langage de script côté serveur, inclus dans du HTML (méta-paquet)
php7.0-cgi - Langage de script intégré à HTML et exécuté côté serveur (binaire CGI)
php7.0-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.0-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.0-curl - CURL module for PHP
php7.0-dev - Files for PHP7.0 module development
php7.0-gd - GD module for PHP
php7.0-gmp - GMP module for PHP
php7.0-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.0-ldap - LDAP module for PHP
php7.0-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.0-odbc - ODBC module for PHP
php7.0-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.0-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for PHP
php7.0-pspell - pspell module for PHP
php7.0-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.0-recode - recode module for PHP
php7.0-snmp - SNMP module for PHP
php7.0-sqlite3 - SQLite3 module for PHP
php7.0-tidy - tidy module for PHP
php7.0-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
php7.0-xmlrpc - XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
php-all-dev - package depending on all supported PHP development packages`

Comment: I'm writing this again. You have a typo here `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstrin` it must be `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`

Comment: sorry it's just when i copy the text it's the same result

Comment: It seems that I found the reason. Maybe you don't have `universe` packages source installed. Check if you have something like this `deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. (change `ru` to your lang code). Have a look here `http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/`. I see that 
 `php7.0-mbstring` is presented.

Comment: i'm really sorry for the late cause i don't see the msg :( 
yes it's right @StanislavYakubenko i don't have in my file source.list the line 
`deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe`
if i download the file from the 2 link you give to me it's should be done and mbstring should be installed.